# Give Docker container VPC access in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, pipeline

I am configuring a CI/CD pipeline using BitBucket Pipelines, and ran into an issue with AWS VPCs. When the pipeline runs integration or end-to-end tests, it needs access to some resources in the VPC, but because the Docker container is outside of it, it is denied access. Is there any way to give access to the Docker container without opening a range of IP addresses to the VPC? The container is never promised the same address at every instance.

Comment: How does your pipeline/ docker container access resources in your VPC ? Are you able to use IAM user or role ? If yes, you could create a user/ role and configure your pipeline to use those credentials to access resources in AWS.